# How do I set a CupertinoTextField border color in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I would like to give a custom border color for the CupertinoTextField in flutter

Comment: Add your code snippet what you have done so far?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `BoxDecoration` and `Border.all` for all sides

```
    CupertinoTextField(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.red)
      ),
    )
```

If you want to have custom colors for each side,

```
    CupertinoTextField(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
        left: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
        top: BorderSide(color: Colors.orange),
        right: BorderSide(color: Colors.yellow),
        bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.green),
      )),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it's `decoration` field and pass a `BoxDecoration` with a border in it like you would with a container.